# Why is the Euclidean metric called the prime at infinity?

Tags: soft-question, notation, p-adic-number-theory

I've been studying p-adic analysis recently and after a bit of searching on the web, I haven't found an answer as to why the Euclidean metric is referred to as the 'prime at infinity', and given the suggestive notation of $|\cdot |_{\infty}$.  Does the p-adic metric for larger and larger primes serve as a better and better approximation of the Euclidean metric, or is it something else?

Comment: This article looks like it might elucidate what you're asking. I only skimmed it but it looks pretty thorough? http://drchristiansalas.wordpress.com/2013/03/02/p-adic-analysis-note-1-the-p-adic-number-field-as-an-ultrametric-completion-of-the-rationals/

Comment: See also [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/91700/in-what-senses-are-archimedean-places-infinite).

Comment: @ZhenLin: The answer in that question is sufficiently far above my head that I can't quite tell whether it would answer my question, but it seems like it might, thanks.

Comment: the link above to the blog of christian salas's blog appears to be dead. But this may be a current version of the original post: https://drchristianphsalas.com/2020/04/24/the-p-adic-number-field-as-a-completion-of-the-rationals/