# Finite/Infinite primes definition in David Cox's "Primes of the form $x^2+ny^2$

Tags: number-theory, commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

Let $K$ be a number field and $\mathcal{O}_K$ its ring of integers. On page 94 of David Cox's Primes of the Form $x^2+ny^2$ (2nd edition), the following definition are made:

> Prime ideals of $\mathcal{O}_K$ are often called *finite primes* to distinguish them from the *infinite primes*, which are determined by the embeddings of $K$ into $\mathbb{C}$. A *real infinite prime* is an embedding $\sigma: K \to \mathbb{R},$ while a *complex infinite prime* is a pair of complex conjugate embeddings $\sigma, \bar{\sigma} : K \to \mathbb{C}, \sigma \neq \bar{\sigma}$. Given an extension $K \subset L,$ an infinite prime $\sigma$ of $K$ ramifies in $L$ provided that $\sigma$ is real but it has an extension to $L$ which is complex. For example, the infinite prime of $\mathbb{Q}$ is unramified in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ but ramified $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-2})$.

I am confused about these definition and need a bit of clarification. To me it seems like a finite prime is just a prime ideal of the ring of integers of $K$. However, infinite primes are defined through some maps, specifically some embeddings? Why are we calling these embeddings primes? Would you also be able to give more details regarding the example given in the last sentence of the quote, or any other example, to illustrate the point?

Comment: Finite and infinite primes of a number field are also called non-archimedean and archimedean [places](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_number_field#Places); they can be identified with the equivalence classes of valuations that one can put on $K$.

Comment: The "why" is a long story.  One motivation (cf. Tate's thesis) is to do Fourier analysis on the ring of adeles of $K$ (which bundles all the completions together in some sense).  Another motivation, at least after the fact, is that many results in class field theory (e.g. the fact that the Galois group of the [Hilbert class field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_class_field) recovers the ideal class group) only work when one considers ramification at infinite places as well as finite ones.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In what senses are archimedean places infinite?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/91700/in-what-senses-are-archimedean-places-infinite)

Comment: Infinite prime is a bit confusing and unmotivated, better to say finite place / infinite place. Place = equivalence class of absolute value on $K$. @RaviFernando I don't think $x\mapsto \log|x|_\infty$ is a valuation (requiring $v(a+b)\ge \min(v(a),v(b))$)