# Infinite primes in number fields

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, prime-factorization, class-field-theory, ramification

David Cox's *Primes of the form $x^2+ny^2$* defines *infinite primes* as

> [Infinite primes] are determined by the embeddings of $K$ into $\mathbb{C}$. A *real infinite prime* is an embedding $\sigma: K \to \mathbb{R},$ while a *complex infinite prime* is a pair of complex conjugate embeddings $\sigma, \bar{\sigma} : K \to \mathbb{C}, \sigma \neq \bar{\sigma}$. Given an extension $K \subset L,$ an infinite prime $\sigma$ of $K$ *ramifies* in $L$ provided that $\sigma$ is real but it has an extension to $L$ which is complex. For example the infinite primes of $\mathbb{Q}$ is unramified in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ but ramified in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-2})$.

i) I looked at this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4541921/finite-infinite-primes-definition-in-david-coxs-primes-of-the-form-x2ny2) and the comments mention calling primes as absolute places. I do know that places are classes of absolute values, but I don't see how they correspond to the real and conjugate embeddings of $K$ into $\mathbb{C}$? Like, for non-archimedean spaces, we work in $\mathbb{Q}_p$ and not $\mathbb{Q}$ so how does this work? If someone could give me an example I would be grateful.

ii) I do not follow the ramification example either? The minimal polynomials are $x^2-2$ and $x^2+2$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ for $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ and $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-2})$ respectively, but I do not understand what they mean by the embeddings/primes ramifying/not ramifying here.

Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 1): Not all places correspond to embeddings of $K$ into $\mathbb{C}$!

Given an *Archimedian* absolute value $v=|\cdot|$ on $K$, the completion $K_v$ is a field of finite dimension over $\mathbb{R}$ (which is the completion of $\mathbb{Q}$ at its only Archimedian place), so $K_v$ is $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$.

Thus, the canonical embedding $K \rightarrow K_v$ produces an embedding $K \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ (or $K \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ up to conjugacy, since the isomorphism $K_v \cong \mathbb{C}$ can be realized in two ways).

Note that $v$ is easily recovered from the embedding: it is (a power of) the restriction of the usual absolute value on $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$.

For 2): consider a number field extension $L/K$. Let $v$ be an Archimedian place of $K$ and $w$ be an Archimedian place of $L$ above $v$. We say that $L/K$ is *ramified* at $w$ if the extension of Archimedian local fields $L_w/K_v$ is nontrivial (ie $L_w \cong \mathbb{C}$ and $K_v \cong \mathbb{R}$).

If $v$ is an Archimedian place of $K$, we say that $L/K$ is ramified at $v$ if there is some place $w$ of $L$ above $v$ such that $L/K$ is ramified at $w$.

For example, $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-2})$ does not embed into $\mathbb{R}$: for any Archimedian place $v$, $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-2})_v\cong \mathbb{C}$, which is not the same as the completion of $\mathbb{Q}$ at its Archimedian place. Therefore, $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-2})/\mathbb{Q}$ is ramified at the Archimedian place of $\mathbb{Q}$.

On the other hand, the image of every embedding $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}) \subset \mathbb{C}$ lands in $\mathbb{R}$: so for any Archimedian place $v$ of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$, $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})_v \cong \mathbb{R}$.

It follows that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}) /\mathbb{Q}$ is not ramified at the Archimedian place of $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Yes, ... although, I think we might have to agree that the terminology for behavior of places/primes at archimedean places, about "ramified" versus (e.g.) "inert", is a bit of a convention, since there are no residue class fields, nor local rings of integers...

Comment: @Aphelli, I see. So only *Archimedean* embeddings are what are considered because only archimedean places embed into $\mathbb{C}$, right? Thank you so much for your answer!

Comment: @paulgarrett  Thank you for the comment, I was going to go ahead and ask just that question next but it helps to know that the terminology is only just convention.